# How to deploy a upgradable proxy contract in mainnet fork using foundry

Tags: hardhat, foundry

```js
const ProxyC = await upgrades.deployProxy(ProxyC, [
    "AD ETH",
    "AAETH",
  ]);
```

I can deploy a plroxy like this in hardhat but how to do it in foundry

Answer (score 0):

There is no straightforward way to do this like Hardhat `upgrades.deployProxy()` does. We used Foundry to develop our contracts but had to use Hardhat to deploy. I think this is a known issue with Foundry as there is no simple way to deploy the proxy admin, proxy and link the implementation.

I will follow this post to see if anyone else chimes in.